# Running / debugging ROS2 Python node with PyCharm on Windows

Tags: ros2, python, ide

I am trying to run (and debug) a ROS2 node made in Python with the PyCharm IDE.

The results won't be exactly the same as `ros2 run ...`, but it seems directly running the relevant script is at least close: `python src/my_project/my_node/node.py`

So in PyCharm I add the Python 3.8 interpreter I use for ROS2 and open the project. So far so good, by adding `C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages` to the [interpreter path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html) I get correct code completion etc.

However, when I try to run my file I am prompted with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\name\project\node.py", line 12, in <module>
    import rclpy   File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from rclpy.signals import install_signal_handlers
File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\signals.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rclpy.exceptions import InvalidHandle
File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rclpy.impl.implementation_singleton import rclpy_implementation as _rclpy
File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\impl\implementation_singleton.py", line 32, in <module>
    rclpy_implementation = import_c_library('._rclpy_pybind11', package)
File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rpyutils\import_c_library.py", line 39, in import_c_library
    return importlib.import_module(name, package=package)
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rclpy_pybind11:

The specified module could not be found.
The C extension 'C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\_rclpy_pybind11.cp38-win_amd64.pyd' failed to be imported while being present on the system.
Please refer to 'https://docs.ros.org/en/{distro}/Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#import-failing-even-with-library-present-on-the-system' for possible solutions
```

I noticed I get the exact same error when running the script from a fresh (unsourced) terminal:

```
C:\dev\ros2_humble\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\name\project\node.py
```

How could I circumvent this in PyCharm?

Comment: I should note: starting `pycharm64.exe` from inside a sourced terminal seems to have _no effect_ on the environment variables in the PyCharm runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer already. I was experimenting running the script from a regular terminal.

Running:

```
C:\dev\ros2_humble\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\name\project\node.py
```

Gives the error: (which is not unexpected)

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy'

I can avoid this by setting `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$Env:PYTHONPATH="C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages"; C:\dev\ros2_humble\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\name\project\node.py
```

Now I get the same error as with PyCharm:

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rclpy_pybind11: The specified module could not be found.

And I found I can fix this by expanding `PATH` with the `bin/` directory of ROS2:

```
$Env:PYTHONPATH="C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages"; $Env:PATH = "C:\dev\ros2_humble\bin;" + $Env:PATH; C:\dev\ros2_humble\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\name\project\node.py
```

Now my node runs!

It seems you can apply the same with PyCharm, edit the run configuration and under "Environment" change "Environment Variables:" to override the `PATH` variable. However, when doing this, the error is *not* fixed...
A quick test with `import os; os.environ["Path"]` at the start of my script shows that `PATH` is not modified at all.

I'm not sure how to continue here.

EDIT: I got it, I need to type "path" under environment variables (no capitals) and I need to specify it in full (i.e. I cannot extend it), but now it works!

Comment: Also see bug report on extending $PATH: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15439/ and my report about overriding $PATH at all: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-64123/